# http streaming using vlc, apache web server

Tags: apache, vlc, http-streaming

I was wondering if you could help me in the following scenario.

Currently I am receiving a udp stream in H.264 format and would like to use vlc to transcode it to a mobile device format and turn it into a stream file which I can then serve using an apache web server.

Does anyone have a tutorial on how to accomplish this?

Thank you.